# WinSCP - Open all files of several directories at once

Tags: file-management, winscp

Is there a way to open all files of several directories at once, in WinSCP?

I went through the menus and some documentation but didn't find a way to do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Shift-F4</kbd> and then type/paste a semicolon separated list of file paths.

[image: Edit list of file paths]

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_edit